# How to determine what colour depth application is using?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bits-per-pixel

If you set BitsPerPixel="32"  in WMAppManifest.xml  file you will have 32 bits colour depth in application. The thing is that low cost devices are always using 16 bits, so images bacome choppy.
I want to determine what value of BitsPerPixel is used in application.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current `SurfaceFormat` from the `GraphicsDevice` like this:

```
// XNA
game.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Format;

// Silverlight
page.SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Format;
```

This returns `SurfaceFormat.Bgr565` for 16-bit color depth and `SurfaceFormat.Color` for 32-bit color depth.